# Bicubic image downscale

Tags: c++, math, image-processing

I want to scale down an image given as a 2 dimensional array using a bicubic filter. Can anyone give me an C++ code snippet to do this?

Comment: If you're doing this to get results, then this is usually done using an image processing library such as http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/.  If you're doing it just to experiment with how bicubic resampling works and learn about it, then follow the advice given by Iulian below.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand the [theory behind it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) (not very difficult). There are a lot of examples, just use a code search engine.

For example [here](https://www.google.com/codesearch#fwGbquBxfFU/trunk/Externals/wxWidgets/src/common/image.cpp&l=628). Look also at the comments.